# SQL Server : how to split table columnName with various delimiters in one function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE tabA (ODN varchar(50))

INSERT INTO tabA (ODN) 
VALUES ('SN1C01'),
       ('DSM07PrdApp20 , DSM10PrdApp06'),
       ('DSM07PrdApp20,BN999999987'),
       ('Dabx,CN2Prd01|CN6PrdGPC06'),
       (''),
       ('CCBBD and CN2PrdGPC01|CN6Prd6');

SELECT * FROM tabA
```

[image]

Comment: Would like to achieve in one function statement with splitting one of rows with multiple delimeter.

Comment: Please do NOT post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, this should be tablular text in the question.

Comment: Please share what you have tried and what problem you have with your query, an error, incorrect results etc.

Comment: I don't know how to write T-SQL to achieve above picture.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2017 or above, you can do it like this...

```
 SELECT [Before] = t.ODN, [After] = TRIM(split2.value)
   FROM tabA t
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(t.ODN,' and ',','),',')split1
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(split1.value,'|')split2
;
```

If not, post a comment on this answer.  There's an alternative for less than 2017.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind marking it as the accepted answer so that folks can tell that it does have an accepted answer if they're looking for a solution?